# What's removing stuff from /var/run at reboots from a fedora machine?

Tags: linux, fedora, milter

I am running a FC18 machine on which I am testing a piece of software (smf-sav, a milter) keeping part of its working files under /var/run/smf-sav/.

That directory keeps disappearing after reboots. Hence the question: what is removing it? Is there a way to mark it permanent?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df -k` on that machine into your question?

Comment: If you software is keeping part in /var/run subdirectory, then repair your system. /var/run is supposed to be clear, period. Refer to http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARRUNRUNTIMEVARIABLEDATA

Comment: The software is by no means "mine". Also keeping sockets under /var/run/<milter-name>/milter-name.sock appears to be somewhat of a standard for milters (see clmav-milter, spamass-milter, etc.) I just noticed their lates startup scripts recreate the dir at boot time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The software should define what directories it needs in */run* (which replaced */var/run* in Fedora 15) by placing a [configuration file](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) in */usr/lib/tmpfiles.d*. During the boot process, [systemd-tmpfiles](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html) populates */run* based on that confguration.

Answer (score 14):

`/var/run` is usually mounted as `tmpfs`, which is a partition mapped into your RAM. Obviously RAM gets cleared on reboot, so do all tmpfs file systems.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/var-run-tmpfs

You should consider storing your application data on a persistent file system e.g. mounted on a hard disk.

Comment: The app is not mine. Also keeping sockets under /var/run/<milter-name>/milter-name.sock appears to be somewhat of a standard for milters (see clmav-milter, spamass-milter, etc.) I just noticed their latest startup scripts recreate the dir at boot time.